# Reading/Writing Data into a Cassandra Cluster

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

I've a Cassandra cluster of 4 nodes with IPs:

1. A:192.168.0.1 (seed provider)
2. B:192.168.0.2
3. C:192.168.0.3
4. D:192.168.0.4

The cluster is configured with a consistency level (CL) of ONE for both read and write.

I want to write/read records into/from the cluster through a web service, but I have a couple of questions:

1. To which node should the web service connect? Does this matter?
2. How does it work with read operations? Say the record was inserted into "B", and the web service tries to read it from "C". Does it still fetch it from "B" if the record is not yet written in "C"?

Would be good if you provide some references.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. To which node should the web service connect? Does this matter?

No, it doesn't really matter which node(s) you tell your service(s) to connect to.  Cassandra uses the [gossip protocol](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureGossipAbout_c.html) to obtain information about the entire cluster, including other nodes that it can connect to.  This is to allow you to add or replace nodes in your cluster, without threatening the availability of your application.

Now with that being said, it is a good idea to give your application a few nodes to connect to.  This will ensure that it can always find an initial node to connect to.

2. How does it work with read operations? Say the record was inserted into "B", and the web service tries to read it from "C". Does it still fetch it from "B" if the record is not yet written in "C"?

Yes with a highly-available, distributed database, you are running under the premise of "eventual [consistency](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html)."  Reading stale data during the [replication](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html) process is possible.

How big of a deal is it?  Netflix did a very good presentation on this titled: [Eventual Consistency != Hopeful Consistency](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/a-netflix-experiment-eventual-consistency-hopeful-consistency-by-christos-kalantzis/).  You should read through the doc as well as watch the video.  The bottom line, is that the time spent being at risk for stale or "dirty reads" is usually low double-digit milliseconds.

So in the end, this really shouldn't be much of a concern unless you are dealing with very high read throughput.  If you find that it is, you can always [increase your read and/or write consistency level](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) for the affected data.